# Select2 Error: Object has no method 'destroy'

Tags: jquery, select, jquery-plugins, jquery-select2

I'm getting this error on line 667 of the select2.js script file. It's the first time select2 is being called on any element on the page.

I'm using version 3.4.2 of the select2 plugin. It's being called on a  element fetched by its id attribute, with no other attributes on the element.

I'm using jQuery version 2.0.3. I've tried other versions of jQuery with no success, as well as a few recent versions of the select2 plugin.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

**Edit** (showing code):

```
<select id="my-select">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#my-select').select2();
</script>
```

Comment: looks fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/TjhMx/1

Answer (score 0):

I had this error.

The problem was that I was initializing it looking for the attribute `data-select2`, with the following code:

```
$('[data-select2=true]').each ->
  $(this).select2()
```

Changing the handler from `data-select2` to `data-bah` worked.